# Changing data type in R

Tags: r, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the column attribute like : all the 0 will become No, all the 1 become Yes. How do I do that in R?

I'm trying to make it using R studio and caret package.

```
    library(mlbench)
    library(caret)
    data<-read.csv('diabetes.csv')
    control<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3)
    model<-train(data$Outcome~.,data=data,method="lvq",preProcess="scale",
                  trControl=control)
```

Here the output gives an error: Error: wrong model type for regression.
This might be because the Outcome column contains 0,1. However it would work if they would be string like: yes, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change data type using

```
    library(dplyr)

    data <- data %>% mutate(Outcome2 = ifelse(Outcome == 1, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Then you use Outcome2 for your model.

Comment: `Outcome2 = (Outcome==1)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library **forcats** and the function `fct_recode()` in order to change the levels of a variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

data <- data %>% mutate(Outcome = fct_recode(as.character(Outcome), 'Yes' = '1', 'No' = '0'))
```